# MSAL on Xamarin Native - OnActivityResult is Never Called, Causing App to Hang on BrowserTabActivity

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-ad-msal

First and foremost this is Xamarin Native, not Xamarin Forms.

In the "SplashActivity" which is set as the MainLauncher=true, I have an async function which calls the AcquireInteractiveToken function. The Browser opens properly, user can authenticate, and the Redirect URI is called and the BrowserTabActivity "UserAuthActivity" opens. However, this is where it ends.

This tab simply remains open, blank, and the activity doesn't seem to "complete" nor is the OnActivityResult function called on "SplashActivity" which would invoke the continuation helper.

Can I not call the MSAL token from a main launcher? Do I have to have a separate activity call it? Why is OnActivityResult never being called?

Activity is declared as such...

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Generic.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
```

Snippets of code from "SplashActivity" related to authentication calls...

```
    private async Task<AuthenticationResult> PerformUserAuthentication()
    {
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();

        try
        {
            IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
            authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(App.Scopes, firstAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)
                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                //await DisplayAlert("Acquire token interactive failed. See exception message for details: ", ex2.Message, "Dismiss");
            }
        }

        return authResult;
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

The BrowserTabActivity which is called properly but doesn't seem to result in calling back to the Splash Activity...

```
[Activity]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
    DataHost = "auth",
    DataScheme = "msal{clientIdIsHere}")]
public class UserAuthActivity : BrowserTabActivity
{
}
```

Comment: The issue is probably your `NoHistory` flag on the Splash Screen. As soon as you navigate away the Splash screen probably gets killed off and Android won't navigate back to it. So yes, you should probably not do your auth on the MainLauncher, in your case your Splash screen, but rather on something that actually stays in your history.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Hmm I follow, that does make a lot of sense. I tried removing NoHistory flag just to see... and it still has the same behavior. I'll try moving the logic to the next activity and see what happens... will update.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Good news! So actually, one thing I didn't notice is... so without the NoHistory flag, you are right, I can get back to the activity. For some reason the BrowserTabActivity stays up, it will not close itself but I can click back to the app and it will hit OnActivityResult now!

Comment: @Cheesebaron Okay, and the other piece of the puzzle is this device doesn't have browser tabs, so I changed to Embedded Web View and we're good! Thanks a MILLION!!!!

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it to work.